# How to update a counter from dictionary Python

Tags: python, counter

I'm new to Python and coding in general and am trying to create a blackjack game in Python but I'm having trouble getting the point counter `point_selection` to update based on the card values in the player's hand:

```
deck_points = {2 : 2, 3 : 3, 4 : 4, 5 : 5, 6 : 6, 7 : 7, 8 : 8, 9 : 9, 10 : 10, 'J' : 10, 'Q' 
: 10, 'K' : 10, 'A' : 11 }

dealer_hand = []
player_hand = []

dealer_points = 0
player_points = 0

def deal_initial_cards(hand, point_selection):
    for i in range(2):
        i = random.choice(list(deck_points))
        hand.append(i)
    for card in hand:
        point_selection += deck_points[card]

deal_initial_cards(dealer_hand, dealer_points)
print(dealer_points)
```

Using the above code, the counter never updates past '0' and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which _counter_?

Comment: I'm trying to get the dealer_points and player_points counters to update with the value's of the cards in dealer_hand and player_hand

Comment: For example: if I called deal_iinitial_cards(dealer_hand, dealer_points), I would want 2 keys from the deck_points dictionary to be appended to dealer_hand and their respective values to be added to dealer_points.

Comment: The function `deal_initial_cards` doesn't do anything with `point_selection`. You can just return the value of the selected cards and add it to `dealer_points` _outside_ the function.

Comment: The keys in your dict `deck_points` are a mix of ints (2,3,...10) and string ('J','Q'). Either make them all strings: '2', '3'...'A'. Or else represent cards by the integers 2..14 and then you only need a list (not a dict) to convert them to string, and another list to get their points value. Ace needs special treatment, since it can have two points values.

Comment: The function `def deal_initial_cards` doesn't have a return statement! (hence it does `return None` by default).  Second, in any case its int argument `point_selection` will only be a copy (since it's an int, which is an immutable type). Your function then modifies the copy and throws away a result. Use an explicit `return point_selection` statement.

Comment: I recommend this not be closed as it's a  small example but a great showcase for Python idiom and decomposition (avoid globals!).

Comment: soggywaffles307: you can click 'Accept' on answers that you found helpful, also you can upvote any answers you want.

Comment: @Jasmijn: the tag 'counter' is relevant, it refers to counters in general, which this is, not specifically Python's `collections.Counter` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a more Pythonic solution that fixes your main bug about your function `deal_initial_cards()` operating on a copy of its (immutable) int argument `point_selection` then throwing away the result, since it doesn't have a `return point_selection` (or store the result in a class member `self.points`). (Also, I made all your dict keys strings: '2','3',.... It's usually customary to represent '10' as 'T' to make all cards a single letter).

But since you're essentially declaring a `Hand` class, then instantiating two objects of it (`dealer_hand`, `player_hand`). `deal_initial_cards()` is essentially a `Hand._init__()` in disguise, so we have a data member `cards` (best not to also call it `hand`). See how simple and clean `ph = Hand()` is; no need for globals. Moreover, we *could* statically compute `points` inside the `__init__()` function and return it (or, better, store it in `self.points` inside each hand object), but that would be a bad decomposition, since if we subsequently add cards to `self.cards`, points wouldn't get updated. So, much more Pythonic is to make `points` a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties) of the class. We then access it
without parentheses: `dh.points`, not `dh.points()`. Last, note the use of a list comprehension (instead of a for-loop-append) to generate `self.hand`. And inside `points()`, note the use of a generator expression `deck_points[card] for card in self.cards`, again more Pythonic than for-loop counter. So this small example is a great showcase of Python idiom and decomposition. We can add a `__str__()` method to Hand. (You could also have a `Card` class, but really that would be overkill.)

```
import random

deck_points = {'2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9, 'T': 10, 'J' : 10, 'Q'
: 10, 'K' : 10, 'A' : 11 }

# No globals, so no need to initialize anything

class Hand:

    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = [random.choice(list(deck_points)) for _ in range(2)]

    @property
    def points(self):
        return sum(deck_points[card] for card in self.cards)

    def __str__(self, join_char=''):
        return join_char.join(card for card in self.cards)

#deal_initial_cards(dealer_hand, dealer_points)
ph = Hand()
dh = Hand()
print('Dealer: ', end='')
print(dh.points)
print('Player: ', end='')
print(ph.points)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. That is super helpful

Comment: Oh, and really, `deck_points` should be a class member hidden inside `Hand`. Then we have no globals, and that's the way good code should be. But for now we're punting on how we represent and convert a 'card' (integer from 1..13 or 2..14 or string '2'...A') to and from its point value, handling the special-case of Ace being worth either '1' or '11'.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I'm still kind of struggling with classes. I recently got through the fist portion of codecademy's comp sci course in python and started struggling towards the end when classes were introduced. Now I'm starting this 2022 complete python bootcamp on udemy to hopefully make some of these ideas more concrete in my brain and get another perspective. I'm just kind of cramming as much as I can until I start an official post bacc comp sci program in March. But again I appreciate the help and would be open to any resources you may have to understand classes better.

Comment: Sure. Read the tutorials, but try stuff out for yourself. Recommend you use [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) for working code, to get tips like this. As distinct to SO, which is for non-working code. Learn how to use both. Also, browse other good Q&A on CodeReview.SE.

Comment: Cramming is bad, ask specific questions (on CodeReview.SE or here). For example, lots of global variables is invariably a code smell that you need classes, or you got the decomposition wrong, or something. Magic methods that update globals only when they get manually called is bad, properties are good. Honestly, a sea of globals is the path to coding hell.

Answer (score 0):

Python ints are immutable, this means `dealer_points` isn't updated. Initialy they have the same id(use `id()`), but when you change the variable inside the function it creates a new variable. To fix your code you need to do something like

```
deck_points = {2 : 2, 3 : 3, 4 : 4, 5 : 5, 6 : 6, 7 : 7, 8 : 8, 9 : 9, 10 : 10, 'J' : 10, 'Q' 
: 10, 'K' : 10, 'A' : 11 }

dealer_hand = []
player_hand = []

dealer_points = 0
player_points = 0

def deal_initial_cards(hand, point_selection):
    for i in range(2):
        i = random.choice(list(deck_points))
        hand.append(i)
    for card in hand:
        point_selection += deck_points[card]
    return point_selection

dealer_points = deal_initial_cards(dealer_hand, dealer_points)
print(dealer_points)
```

whereas a list, which you probably noticed, is mutable. This means the list inside the function stays the same(keeps its id) even when its edited.

Comment: This has nothing to do with "pass by reference / value" and  everything to do with mutable / immutable types.

Comment: Sorry i was mistaken with c++, i will edit it. Thanks!

Comment: That seems to have fixed it and I understand what I did wrong now. Thank you!

Comment: Immutable types also have the same `id` inside the function before they are modified. Try `print(id(dealer_points))` before calling the function and `print(id(point_selection))` in the function before modifying it.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I have edited my answer, hopefully it's completely correct now!